# find sigma Algebra of X

Tags: probability

If the function $X:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $X:=I_{[0,1]}+4I_{[2,4]}.$

What is $\sigma(X)$

Could it be
$\{B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3:B_1\subseteq\{[0,1]\},B_2\subseteq\{[2,4]\},
B_3\subseteq \{(-\infty,1)\cup(1,2)\cup(4,\infty)\}\}$ ??

Comment: How is $\sigma(X)$ defined?

Answer (score 1):

Alllmost.

If the outcome set is $\Bbb R$, then $X$ does indeed partition this into $\big\{[0..1],[2..4], (-\infty..0)\cup(1..2)\cup(4..\infty)\big\}$.

You may label these parts as $B_1, B_2, B_3$ respectively. $${B_1=[0..1]\\B_2=[2..4]\\B_3=(-\infty..0)\cup(1..2)\cup(4..\infty)}$$

Okay, then the sigma algebra for $X$ is the closure of this partition, under countable unions, intersections, and complementation.

$$\{\emptyset, B_1, B_2, B_3, \underset{\textsf{some more sets}}{\ldots,\ldots,\ldots}, \Bbb R\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sigma (X)$ is same as $\sigma ([0,1],[2,4])$. In general $\sigma (A,B)=\{ \varnothing, \mathbb  R, A,B,A^{c},B^{c}, A\cap B, B\cup A, B^{c}\cap A, B\cap A^{c},B^{c}\cup A, B\cup A^{c}, B^{c}\cup A^{c},B^{c}\cap A^{c}\}$.